# PHP array to CSV issues

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv

I have an array:
`$rowcsv['reasonforabsence']` this contains an undetermined amount of values.
I want to output the values of this array to a CSV along with other values like this:

```
fputcsv($output, array( $overtime, $rowcsv['reasonforabsence']));
```

But when I do this the CSV outputs:

```
|6|"Holiday Full Day,Sick Full Day,Sick AM,Sick PM,Holiday Full Day,Holiday AM,Holiday PM,Absent Full Day,Absent AM|`
```

So basically instead of the `$rowcsv['reasonforabsence']` array putting the values into new cells the array is just putting all the values into 1 cell.
I have tried:

`$reasonforabsence = explode( ',', $rowcsv['reasonforabsence'] );`

`$reasonforabsence = implode('","', $reasonforabsence);`

But I get the output:

`"Holiday Full Day"",""Sick Full Day"",""Sick AM"",""Sick PM"",""Holiday Full Day"",""Holiday AM"",""Holiday PM"",""Absent Full Day"",""Absent AM"`

And everything still appears in 1 cell just this time with the quotes.

Comment: What does one line of your `$rowcsv['reasonforabsence']` actually look like, please add a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` and what does `$overtime` look like

Comment: You could also try adding the last 2 parameter to `fputcsv($output, array( $overtime, $rowcsv['reasonforabsence']), ',', '"');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `$overtime` and `$rowcsv['reasonforabsence']` into a single array using `array_merge` and pass the combined array to `fputcsv`

```
$row = array_merge(array($overtime),explode(',',$rowcsv['reasonforabsence']));
fputcsv($output,$row);
```

Comment: Nice one. I had to explode the `$rowcsv['reasonforabsence']` string into an array but it works as I wanted. Ive been trying for about 6 hours to solve it so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With `array( $overtime, $rowcsv['reasonforabsence'])` you construct an array with two entries.
Accordings  `$rowcsv['reasonforabsence']` is a plain comma separated values string, you have to explode() this into an array and merge it with your $overtime value :

```
fputcsv($output, array_merge(array($overtime), explode(',', $rowcsv['reasonforabsence'])));
```